# Ubuntu 22.10 on USB Stick with no previous program or partitions but Bios has no USB option to Boot from

Tags: boot, usb

New Ubuntu user coming from Linux Cinnamon 20.3 trying to install Ubuntu 20.10 on my Hard Drive for the first time

Using Rufus I put Ubuntu 22.10 on a USB Stick all went well without problems as it was a Clean Transfer to the New USB Stick with no previous programs or partitions

The Problem is my Bios doesn't show any USB option to boot from, so I am completely lost as to what I should do

As a Newbie to Ubuntu please explain as clearly as you can

Comment: Ubuntu 20.10 is EOL and not supported here.  Are you certain that is not a typo?  If it is not a typo, I recommend that you download either Ubuntu 20.04 LTS, 22.04 LTS or 22.10.

Comment: Sorry! Yes! it was a Typo I meant 22.10

Comment: When you used Rufus, did you make sure that you let it do the UEFI and not Legacy?  See https://rufus.ie/en/ and you will see Target System as *UEFI not CSM*

Comment: Hi I just let Rufus do its thing and Ubuntu 22.10 is now on my USB Stick the problem is there is No USB Boot Option to Select from in the Bios, once that is solved I know what I am doing

Comment: If the EFI files were not put in the proper location on the USB, the BIOS may not see it as a boot device at all.  I would recommend trying to re-run Rufus again on it and make sure that the proper settings are selected.  I can't go any further than this as I don't use a UEFI bios on my system, but I do know that the files have to be in the right locations for it it to work.

Comment: There is No Usb Boot option in my Bios

Comment: Often when I am booting a installer USB, I need to press ESC, F8, F9, F10 or F12, (depending on computer make), to select the drive to boot.

Comment: Hi Slightly Good News!